# Webpack unhelpful warnings after compilation with Laravel Mix

Tags: webpack, warnings, laravel-mix, polyfills, autoprefixer

I'm trying to use CSS grids polyfill for IE10-11 with postCSS and Autoprefixer. I'm using Laravel Mix in a Laravel project. I'm having the most difficult time debugging Webpack's output.

After I run `npm run dev`, I get the following warnings :

```
444 WARNINGS in child compilations
webpack compiled with 444 warnings
```

And that's it. No more info. Polyfills are rightfully applied under IE but not displaying correctly. I'm hoping those warnings could help fixing my issue. I read the Laravel Mix docs but in vain, no mentions of warnings or debugging whatsoever, and I'm not well experienced with Webpack.

How can I get some details about those warnings ?